# OutOfBoundsException error when creating an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make a deck of cards. So far I have this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Card {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> rank = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Ace", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"));
        ArrayList<String> suite = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"));
        ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
        String card;


        for (int i = 0; i < rank.size(); i++) {
            for (int p = 0; i < suite.size(); p++) {
                card = rank.get(i) + " of " + suite.get(p);
                deck.add(card);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(deck);
    }
}
```

I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException error on this line:

```
card = rank.get(i) + " of " + suite.get(p);
```

Comment: Look at that again ----> `int p = 0; i < suite.size(); p++`

Comment: This is a typical typo question and hey no problem happens to everybody... but I suggest that you do not accept answer and maybe even delete it (you will get your rep points back) to keep SO clean.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the second loop:

```
for (int p = 0; i < suite.size(); p++) {
```

should be

```
for (int p = 0; p < suite.size(); p++) {
```

Comment: wow thanks! I feel like an idiot for not noticing lol

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're using `i < suite.size();` in your inner for loop